# OnClick in a gridview

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two different gridviews, the first one is being populated by the table names in my database schema and the second gridview is populated with the definition of a table that you click on in the first gridview.  Sometimes when you click on a table name it doesn't populate the second gridview with the information.  It highlights the cell in the first gridview that you clicked on but it does not update the second gridview.

Here is the code for the cellcontentclick for the first gridview:

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        _dft.Rows.Clear();
        selectedtext = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();
        List<CreateTables> lstTables = mCreateTables.getTableInfo(Convert.ToString("'" + textSearch + "'"), Convert.ToString("'" + selectedtext + "'"));
        //form2.buildDataTable();
        if (lstTables != null)
        {
            foreach (CreateTables fillFields in lstTables)
            {
                fillingSpaces = fillFields.ColumnHeading;
                fillingSpaces = Regex.Replace(fillingSpaces, @"\s+", " ");
                longname = fillingSpaces.Replace(" ", "_");
                description = fillingSpaces;
                shortname = fillFields.ColumnName;
                length = Convert.ToInt32(fillFields.Length);
                if (fillFields.Decimal == "")
                    decimallength = 0;
                else
                    decimallength = Convert.ToInt32(fillFields.Decimal);
                type = fillFields.DataType;
                newRowFile();

            }
        }    
    }
```

I am just trying to figure out why there seems to be some lag when you click on them, most of the time it is if you click on them in a quick manner.

EDIT: After clicking around a bunch it seems to not populate the second gridview if you don't click directly on the text, even the little space above and below the text does not work.

Comment: That's what CellContentClick is all about — clicking on the "content".  Try using the CellClick instead.

Comment: __Do not__ call a `DataGridView`a `GridView`!! This is wrong and confusing.. Always call things by their __right__ name! Yes, it takes __four__ letters more to type, but when asking for help here is __not__ the time to be so lazy..! -